# Swagger Path Selector Not Working

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

We are in a process of implementing Swagger for our REST APIs in a Spring Boot Application. Along with adding YAML files, we have also made changes to Spring Boot configurations to include a reg-ex pattern.

```
@Bean("myApi")
public Docket myApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
        .paths(myApiPaths())
        .build()
        .pathMapping("/");
}

private Predicate<String> myApiPaths() {
    return PathSelectors.regex("/v1/my/path/.*");
}
```

Currently all such YAML files are included in one library and are always available for all spring boot components. Because of this swagger-ui shows up all end points defined. This is why we were relying on path selectors so that only those matching patterns will be exposed.

But above code does not seem to be working. Despite trying different regex patterns, RequestHandlers I am still seeing the APIs which are not implemented on given Spring Boot Component.

Any help here will be appreciated.

Comment: if you are using `/` in your pathMapping it will show everything. Doesn't seem to be working is not a good explanation

Comment: @pvpkiran, thanks for your feedback. I edited my question to add more details. To answer your question, yes, I have tried different combinations and that still showed me the APIs which are not implemented by this component.

Comment: you cna try excluding the one's you dont need like this `.paths(PathSelectors.regex("(?!/error).+")).paths(PathSelectors.regex("(?!/internal).+"))`

Comment: I have tried this. PathSelectors does not seem to have any effect on what is displayed on swagger-ui.html page. Even if I have any string, even a bad regular expression pattern, still swagger-ui displays all APIs.